# First iteration doesnt work in python on certain inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone explain why does line 11 work, but 13 doesnt, **when the input is 3 and 6**.
More broadly, why doesnt the first iteration of the for loop work?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sympy, math

x,y = map(int,input("Enter x and y separated with space\n").split())

if (y/x).is_integer()!=True or sympy.isprime(int(y/x))=="True":
    a,b=0,0

else:
    print("THIS LINE WORKS")
    for i in range(1, int((y/x)/2)):
        print("THIS LINE WONT WORK")
        j=1
        while ((i**j)<=(y/x)):
            print(i," is i and",j, " is j")
            if (i**j)==(y/x):
                b,a=i,j
                i=int((y/x)/2)
                break
            if i==1 and j==(y/x): i+=1
            j+=1        
        
# print(a,b, sep=" ")
```

snap showing line 11 and 13
[image]

Comment: When you say: `"but 13 doesnt"`, what is the input in this case?

Comment: Where is line 11? Where line 13?

Comment: @quamrana the inputs are 3 and 6: already mentioned.

Comment: @9769953 y/x would always be an int since the lines above already takes care of that

Comment: `int((y/x)/2)` equals 1 for your input. Try on the command line.

Comment: 6/3=2.0     .......

Comment: You really should try and print some of your test cases, and see what values and types they result in. That would have explained your problem instantly.

Comment: Please don't use pictures of code: they can't be searched, can't be copy-pasted, and people with screenreaders can't read them.

Comment: Did you know you can debug your code yourself? Set break points, inspect variables, expressions. All becomes much clearer then...

Comment: @9769953 pardon me, I was lost

Comment: @trincot i agree to you, now i realize my stupidity

Comment: @9769953 `is_integer()` is a `float` method that indicates whether a floating point number is equivalent to an integer; it's not the same as `isinstance(..., int)`.  (A better way to write the check `if (y/x).is_integer() != True` would be simply `if y % x`, though.)

Comment: @Samwise Whoops, my bad. I guess because I never use it (I would indeed use a modulo operator), didn't think it through and put it in the category useless. Going to delete some comments. Apologies to karthiknair for that.

Comment: @9769953 i posted the code as text only. the below pic only shows which were lines 11 and 13.

Comment: It'd probably be easier to just put a trailing comment on those lines, with the line number. E.g, `for i in range(1, int((y/x)/2)):  # line 11` or something.

Comment: @9769953 sorry man. My brain wasnt working. Ig I should quit programming.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "first iteration of the for loop".

```
>>> x, y = 3, 6
>>> int((y/x)/2)
1
```

`range(1, 1)` is empty, so there's nothing to iterate over.